# Gradle cache conflicting with original library?

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

I am building a Nativescript plugin, for android. When I add the Azure-Mobile-SDK (`azure-mobile-android-3.1.0.jar`), I get the following error:

```
:buildMetadata
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.query.FunctionCallNodeMerger conflict: /Users/georgeedwards/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mobile-android/3.1.0/ae6cfa31ba5a84141676d2d92fa64ca36c52d28/azure-mobile-android-3.1.0.jar and /Users/georgeedwards/Desktop/nativescript-plugin-seed-master/demo/node_modules/nativescript-yourplugin/platforms/android/azure-mobile-android-3.1.0.jar
    at com.telerik.metadata.ClassRepo.cacheJarFile(ClassRepo.java:21)
    at com.telerik.metadata.Builder.build(Builder.java:38)
    at com.telerik.metadata.Generator.main(Generator.java:44)
:buildMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

It looks as though the cached version is conflicting with my original library and causing my build to fail - why is this happening and how can I stop it?

If I delete the Gradle cache before my build, I still get the same issue. So it seems the conflicting cache copy is being created during the build process...

Update, if I don't list the library in my `include.gradle`, then I get the following output:

```
:buildMetadata
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ApiJsonOperationCallback
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.LoginManager
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceConnection
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.MobileServiceHttpClient
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.NextServiceFilterCallback
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.OkHttpClientFactory
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.OkHttpClientFactoryImpl
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilter
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterRequest
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterRequestImpl
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterResponse
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilterResponseImpl
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.notifications.MobileServicePush
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceConflictExceptionJson
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceExceptionBase
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceJsonTable
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServicePreconditionFailedExceptionJson
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceTable
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.TableJsonQueryCallback
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.query.ExecutableJsonQuery
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.query.ExecutableQuery
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.serialization.DateSerializer
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.serialization.JsonEntityParser
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.serialization.LongSerializer
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.MobileServiceJsonSyncTable
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.MobileServiceSyncContext
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.MobileServiceSyncTable
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.localstore.MobileServiceLocalStore
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.localstore.SQLiteLocalStore
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.AbstractTableOperation
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.DeleteOperation
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.LocalTableOperationProcessor
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.RemoteTableOperationProcessor
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.TableOperation
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.TableOperationError
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.pull.IncrementalPullStrategy
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.pull.PullStrategy
    Error: java.lang.NullPxception
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.queue.OperationQueue
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.synchandler.MobileServiceSyncHandler
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.synchandler.SimpleSyncHandler
    Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 'assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat'...
 'assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat'...
 'assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat'...
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
```

But it builds successfully - any ideas why the include is an issue?

Comment: Try deleting your cache, `rm -rf ~/.gradle`. **Warning:** Will remove all cache and `gradle.properties`. or you can try `gradle --refresh-dependencies -i` and that will refresh the cache.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I think that it is the actual build that is producing the conflicting cache, when I did the full remove, I still faced the same issue...

Comment: `actual build`. Can you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: I have an include.gradle - ```dependencies {
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.1.0'
} ```

Comment: @JaredBurrows see above